# Centering LabelField in HorizontalFieldManager in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I added HorizontalFieldManager to screen with backgroundcolor and with specific width and height.And i added a labelField to hfm.But labelfield displaying at top in hfm.How can i adjust it to center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

LabelField.setMargin(Hfm height/2, 15, 0, 15);

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the style of the labelfield to LabelField.Field_HCENTER? This should work for you